# remove a cell from array give me run time error

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, runtime-error

i have a template array consist Cells that  holds the data, described in the code:

```
template <class T>
class Array
{
private:
    //the array is consist cellss that holds the data
    template<class S>
    class Cell
    {
    public:
        //members:
        S* m_data;

        //methods:
        //C'tor:(inline)
        Cell(S* data=NULL): m_data(data){};
        //D'tor:(inline)
        ~Cell(){delete m_data;};
        //C.C'tor:(inlnie)
        Cell(const Cell<S>& cell):  m_data(cell.m_data){};
    };
private:
    //members of Array:
    Cell<T>* m_head,*m_last;
    unsigned int m_size;
public:
    /*******************C'tors and D'tors************************/
    //C'tor:(inline)
    Array():m_head(NULL),m_last(NULL), m_size(0){};
    //D'tor:
    ~Array(){delete[] m_head;};
    //C.C'tor:
    Array(const Array& array): m_head(array.m_head),m_last(array.m_last),m_size(array.m_size){};

    /****************Adding********************/
    //add an element to the end of the Array:
    void add(const T added);

    /*******************Returning and deleting***********************/
    T& operator[](const unsigned int index)const {return *(m_head[index].m_data);};
    //delete the last element:
    void remove();

    /*********************Size*****************************/
    //returning the number of elements:(inline)
    const unsigned int size()const{return m_size;};
    //check if the Array is empty:
    bool isEmpty()const {return (m_size==0);};


};
```

now this is the implementaion of add:(after tests look like it works fine but just for case i write it here also)

```
template <class T>void Array<T>::add(const T added)
{
    //allocating memory for the new array:
    Cell<T>* newarray=new Cell<T>[m_size+1];

    //copy all the elements from the old array:
    unsigned int i;
    for (i=0; i<m_size;i++)
        newarray[i].m_data=m_head[i].m_data;

    //put the added in the last index:
    T* newelement= new T(added);
    newarray[i].m_data=newelement;

    //change the ptrs:
    m_head=newarray;
    m_last=&newarray[m_size];

    //increase the counter:
    m_size++;
}
```

and this is the implementaion of remove:

```
template <class T>void Array<T>::remove()
{
    //if there is only 1 element:
    if(m_size==1)
    {
        delete[] m_head;
        m_head=m_last=NULL;
    }
    //change the last the previus cell 
    else
    {
        delete m_last;
        m_last=m_last-1;
    }
    //and decrease the counter:
    m_size--;
}
```

now when do:

```
Array<int> a;
a.add(3);//work fine
a.add(4);//work fine
a.remove();//fail
```

i get a runtime error from the line `delete m_last;` even though m_last point to a cell that  actually hold data (m_last point to a cell holds 4).
what am i missing here? why cant i delete a pointer to a cell in the Array?

the error VS2012 give me:`_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VAILED(pHead->nBlockUse)`

another important thing i forgot to say: when debug it doesnt enter the D'tor of Cell at all, it just get out when going to the delete.

Comment: You have a few mistakes in your code, which means that when you fix this problem you will run into others. If you are deleting dynamically allocated memory, make sure that the object doing that actually owns that memory, and that no other object trying to do the same. Look at [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Answer (score 3):

You can't delete one element of array.

```
int *x = new int[10];
delete &x[2] ; // It is incorrect!
```

You can only delete whole of array:

```
delete [] x;
```

Comment: ok, but what i need to do when i want to the delete the last element and disconnect it from the array? also i want to avoid memory leak

Comment: It is also worth to mention that you can do it like that:
int **x = new int*[10];
x[1] = new int(2);
delete x[1];
if you wanted to delete array elements one by one. And it seems like you do.

Comment: @AviadChmelnik With your current data structure, you would have to copy the elements to a new array, delete the old one and adjust the pointers.

Comment: @juanchopanza `Array:add()` says `m_last=&newarray[m_size]` and `Array::remove()` says `delete m_last`, which boils down to exactly the problem that A.Danesh describes.

Comment: may i use this soulotion: just change the pointers of last and decrease the m_size member. the last we didnt delete will deleted in the D'tor of the array (which will be called in the end of the program or in the add method). what do you think?

Comment: @Oswald You are completely right, it is a clear double delete. I didn't see it due to all the other errors.

Comment: @AviadChmelnik Your new solution is better, but you can improve it by store the count of array in m_available_size. When you add new item, if the array has any empty elements, you don't need to reallocate it.

Answer (score 2):

The destructor `~Cell` calls `delete`. That's a sure sign that the constructor should call `new`.

Comment: look at the comment in the end, it doesnt enter the destructor of Cell. also the new of T object is make in the add method only

Comment: Don't do that. Don't `new` an object in one class and `delete` it in a differnen class. It is error prone. Use the [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) idiom instead.